# What am I missing in this TSQL (like operator)?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, pattern-matching

```
select c.* 
from syscolumns c join sysobjects o on o.id=c.id and o.name = 'orders'
```

returns

```
Id
Customer
Product
03-28-2011
04-04-2011
04-11-2011
04-18-2011
```

This is correct. But I want only the columns that match the pattern 99-99-9999. So I tried this `where cast(o.name as varchar) like '%-%-%'` which didn't return any results. Then I tried this: `where cast(o.name as varchar) like 'P%'` (I expected to get "Product") and it also did not return anything. Why??? What syntax should I use to get the columns that are "dates" ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each part of your question...

### Date pattern matching

You can use [0-9] to specify ranges.

So for `99-99-9999` you'd have

```
LIKE '[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

For dates, you can use ISDATE too or things like this to restrict further

```
LIKE '[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-2[0-9][0-9][0-9]'
```

### Column filters

These conditions can never all be true because they are *all* on `o.name`

```
o.name = 'orders'
```

and

```
cast(o.name as varchar) like '%-%-%'
cast(o.name as varchar) like 'P%'
```

The latter 2 should be on `c.name` in your query

### Finally

Use the newer sys.columns and sys.objects. Or INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS which is probably best here

Answer (score 0):

You are casting to varchar without providing a length. I believe that the default is 1 which would explain the problem.

Provide a length in the cast statement as follows.

```
varchar(50)
```

Edit: No. The default for cast and convert is 30.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176089.aspx

Comment: It's 30 in CAST/CONVERT, 1 for DECLARE

Comment: Thanks Scott. Actually the Cast is not necessary. This was me trying to make the like work, but as pointed out by gbn, I had a wrong table name on the name column (sysobjects.name instead of syscolumns.name).